# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un objeto a un archivo JSON mediante Bash?

Tags: json, bash

Tengo este JSON con la información de un usuario:

```
{
"login": [
    {
        "ID": "1536", 
        "username": "user1",
        "pass": "1234"
    },
    {
        "ID": "5367",
        "username": "user2"
   }]
}
```

A `user2` le falta la contraseña.

User2 tiene que crearse una contraseña con una línea de comando

Quiero que la contraseña que ponga se guarde ahí como:

```
"pass": "5678".  (Debajo de "username": "user2")
```

Comment: creo que directamente no lo puedes hacer , la unica forma que se me ocurre es crear otra vez el archivo y enviar los valores

Comment: ¿pero no se puede hacer con algún archivo externo?

Comment: Con funcionalidad Bash, entiendo que es posible pero complicado, ¿Te sirve una solución Bash + python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una herramienta para tratar JSON desde línea de comanados. Se llama [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) y resulta bastante sencillo trabajar con ella.

En este caso específico lo que debes hacer es añadir un elemento al 2.º grupo del bloque `login`. Es decir:

```
jq '.login[1] |= . + {"pass": "5678"}'
```

Lo que nos devuelve:

```
$ jq '.login[1] |= . + {"pass": "5678"}' fichero
{
  "login": [
    {
      "ID": "1536",
      "username": "user1",
      "pass": "1234"
    },
    {
      "ID": "5367",
      "username": "user2",
      "pass": "5678"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Gracias a esto utilicé.   jq '.login[0] |= . + {"pass": "1234"}' login.json > tmp.$$.json && rm login.json && jq '.' tmp.$$.json > login.json && rm tmp.$$.json

Comment: @iknxhk me parece que lo complicas un poco, pero genial si te funcionó. Lo que no entiendo es que hayas aceptado y desaceptado esta respuesta tres veces :P

Comment: a esque primera vez que uso stackoverflow por eso y lo que hice fue utilizar la linea de comando y guardar lo que sale en otro archivo, despues elimino el que le falta el objeto y crear nuevamente el archivo con el objeto nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Como veo que te sirven soluciones alternativas a `bash` básico, puedes usar `python` para resolverlo, hoy es raro que no venga ya instalado en cualquier distribución Linux. La idea es generar dinámicamente un Script que tome la entrada de una archivo Json y agregue la clave `pass` en cualquier elemento de la lista "login" que pudiera estar faltando, lo siguiente lo salvas como un script de shell, por ejemplo `procesarjson.sh` y le das permisos de ejecución con `chmod +x procesarjson.sh`:

```
##############################################################
# Creamos un Script Python (Debiera ser compatible con 2x/3x)
##############################################################
scriptpy="$(mktemp).py"
cat > $scriptpy << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json

default_pass = "5678"

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  data = json.loads(f.read())

for e in data["login"]:
  e["pass"] = e.get("pass", default_pass)

print(json.dumps(data))
EOF
##############################################################
# Ejecutamos el Script recibiendo la entrada estándar
##############################################################
python "$scriptpy" $1

rm "$scriptpy"
```

La ejecución es tan sencilla como `./procesarjson.sh archivo.json`, se generará nuevamente el Json por la salida estándar pero con el agregado del password dónde no existiera.

Comment: Me parece un poco _overkilling_ hacer un script que lo que hace es llamar a un script de Python. ¿Por qué no directamente un script con Python? En cualquier caso, +1 por la versión en Python, que seguramente podría extenderse dando el `default_pass` por parámetro.